# Yii verify a child of child

Tags: php, yii, rbac

I have `role = "reporting"`, which has a task `child = "reporting.task"`, which has an operation `child = "reporting.task.create"`; but the following:

```
if(Yii::app()->authManager->hasItemChild($reportingRole,$reportingTaskCreateOperation))
```

evaluates to false.

How can I check that operation `"reporting.task.create"` is assigned to role `"reporting"`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
isset( Yii::app()->authManager->getItemChildren('roleName')['taskName'] );
```